How to catch event on Leaflet map ready(fully rendered)?
I need an event when the full map is ready to use.
I want to take a screenshot, but sometimes the map is not ready and gray blocks appear on it. image
I`m using SimpleMapScreenshoter for this
I've played with timeouts before, but it work randomly. And as I understand whenReady() event don't grant you full map initializing

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
